# Group by column, result limit and sort by another column rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say we have models `ItemStatistic` and `Book`.
`ItemStatistic` example record:

```
  item_id: 15,
  book_id: 3,
  score: 0.25192368e4,
```

Book example:

```
  id: 3,
  title: 'Harry Potter',
```

We need to group the `ItemStatistic` records by `item_id`, then order results for each `item_id` key by `score` and limit the number of values for each `item_id` key by `3` and return not `ItemStatistic` records but `Book`.
Example:

```
{15: [{id: 3, title: 'Harry Potter'}, {id: 4, title: 'The Chronicles of Narnia'},...], 2: [...]}
```

or

```
{1: [{},{},{}], 2: [{},{},{}], 3:[{},{},{}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the desire correctly, the following should work

```
item_statistics_table = ItemStatistic.arel_table 
filter = Arel::Table.new('filtered_results')
sub_query = item_statistics_table.project(
  item_statistics[Arel.star],
  Arel.sql('ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY item_statistics.item_id 
              ORDER BY item_statistics.score DESC
            )').as('row_num')
)

query = Arel::Nodes::As.new(sub_query, Arel.sql(filter.name))

join_clause = Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(
    query,
    Arel::Nodes::On.new(
      Book.arel_table[:id].eq(filter[:book_id])
        .and(filter[:row_num].lteq(3))
    )
  )

Book
 .select(Book.arel_table[Arel.star],filter[:item_id])
 .joins(join_clause)
 .group_by(&:item_id)
```

This should result in the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    books.*,
    filtered_results.item_id
FROM 
    books 
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT 
        item_statistics.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
          PARTITION BY item_statistics.item_id 
          ORDER BY item_statistics.score DESC
        ) as row_number
      FROM 
        item_statistics
    ) AS filtered_results ON books.id = filtered_results.book_id 
            AND filtered_results.row_number <= 3
```

Then we are grouping all the books by the `item_id` (virtual attribute) so the result is

```
{1 => [Book,Book,Book], 2 => [Book,Book,Book]}
```

Resulting size of the Array should be <= 3 (in the event an item_id has less than 3 records) identical scores are not taken into account.